# python ldap3 search LDAPOperationsErrorResult

Tags: python, ldap

I would like to get all PCs in the local network from ldap, so I tried (variations of) this:

```
import ldap3
from ldap3 import ALL_ATTRIBUTES, SUBTREE, ALL
import dns.resolver
import socket

def get_ldap_server():
    domain_name = socket.getfqdn().lstrip( socket.gethostname() )    
    answers = dns.resolver.query( '_ldap._tcp'+domain_name, rdtype='srv' )
    #for srv in answers:
    return answers[0].target.to_text()[:-1]

srv_name = get_ldap_server()
print srv_name
server = ldap3.Server( srv_name, get_info=ALL )
with ldap3.Connection( server ) as c:
    print "Bound", c.bound
    c.search( search_base='dc='+', dc='.join(srv_name.split('.')[1:]),
          search_filter='(objectCategory=computer)',
          search_scope=SUBTREE,
          attributes=ALL_ATTRIBUTES,
          get_operational_attributes=True)

    print(c.response)
```

But all I get is: 
LDAPOperationsErrorResult: LDAPOperationsErrorResult - 1 - operationsError - None - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C090748, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v2580 - searchResDone - None

Despite "Bound" being "True".

I'm using python 2.7. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: As cannatag points out, I need to authenticate to get this information. The error-message sucks, though, because the bind actually succeeded, which is why without (t)his help, I got stuck.\rant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't provide any username or password in the connection object, so an anonymous bind is performed.

Try adding username=xxx and password=yyy to the Connection definition in the "with" statement.

Comment: Is it possible to get the current user's credentials to log on with?
It seems to work on the linux commandline, e.g.
    ldapsearch -H "ldap://dc.domain.com" -b "dc=domain,dc=com" "objectclass=computer" 
is enough, you're not required to give the user credentials (again).

Comment: Here you're searching for objectclass=computer while in the code in your original question you're using objectCategory=computer. These are two different attribute types (http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx#Filter_on_objectCategory_and_objectClass).